# Trying to make UI button interactable over input field when touch screen keyboard in enabled for iOS in unity3D

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, keyboard, touchscreen

Its a chatting scene, i have an input field for typing message and beside it there is a send button. Now while touch screen keyboard is enabled i can not press the send button, first the keyboard goes downwards and then i have to click the send button. Any suggestion?

Comment: I'd use the return/done/ok/whatever key on the keyboard instead of a separate key inside the game.

Comment: yes thats i know, but requirements is different here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script for your input field that detects when the focus is inside of the GUI element, and check the TouchScreenKeyboard.visible variable to know when it is dismissed.